# If I delete downvoted question, do I get reputation back?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, deleted-questions

I have posted a [question on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641281/cant-get-wxwidgets-example-from-tutorial-to-work/21650896#21650896) After a while, after no one responded with a working solution, I found the answer to the question myself, and wrote it.

Then for some reason, I got a downvote. My question is, do I get reputation back if I delete this question ? I want to get reputation back, because I don't see a reason why I should lose it. I don't see what I did wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You will get the reputation back, but if you end up question banned (which can happen), deleted questions just push you deeper and faster into the question ban and make it harder to get out of it.

Comment: To add to the above - a single upvote on either question or answer would gain you more reputation than any you have lost from the single downvote. Now, other people who come across the question in the future may benefit from your experience - why deny them this benefit?

Comment: I don't want to deny anyone from this benefit. I posted the question in good hope to help myself and possibly others too. But I only got 1 vote since the question was posted, and it was a downvote, after I found the answer. So I thought the question is not of much use, beside lowering my reputation.

Comment: Well, you never know who may benefit from it in the future. I can't speak as to why it got downvoted - could be that someone didn't like that it was self-answered, or some other random reason. Consider that that's all it is - a single, random downvote. Easily offset by a single possible upvote in the future by someone you helped ;)

Comment: @Oded - Right, I will accept your view of the situation :) And I really hope this question may be useful to anyone in the future. Thank you =)

Comment: I endorse what Oded said: a single downvote is nothing to worry about, and certainly not worth deleting a post over. There will always be some people on Stack Overflow who vote in ways that don't make sense.

Comment: The next question would be: If the question will benefit others then you should not delete it. But it is worth the permanent sacrifice of that man's access and future "contributing on" such topics. So if downvotes then delete. We downvote in that purpose. The man's sacrifice to only produce once that purposeful question/answer and get banned forever - it that the real cause - then delete, no experience no years of involvement... no fate. Better del (it's fair). The downvotes show the quality. And extremely low --- show of non-quality material. But if this helps the SE resource to survive let i

Comment: In my case I've got like 13 downvotes on one feature request post, and I thought leaving it there might do someone a service--but it seems the longer I leave it up, the more it's seriously doing a disservice to my reputation!